# add multiple rows for a range of variable and condtional column to a file

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I have a file with 4 columns. First two columns are for x and y position (in integers) and third, fourth column for an arbitrary field value.

```
1 1 0.5 1.2 
1 2 1.7 2.3
1 3 2.0 2.2 
2 1 1.4 2.5
2 2 1.6 3.0
2 3 2.35 2.9
3 1 2.0 2.9
3 2 0.7 2.5
3 3 0.2 2.1
```

To this input file, I want to add two columns between second and third columns
For each value of x,y in first two columns a z value from 1 to 3 should be added as a third column. Finally, a fourth column should be added with a value such that

```
if (z<$3 ) value = 0
if (z>=$3 && z <=$4) value = 1
if (z >$4) value = 2
```

note that $3 are $4 are the column values in the input file and $4 is always greater than $3.

The output file should look like

```
1 1 1 1 0.5 1.2 
1 1 2 2 0.5 1.2 
1 1 3 2 0.5 1.2 
1 2 1 0 1.7 2.3
1 2 2 1 1.7 2.3
1 2 3 2 1.7 2.3    
1 3 1 0 2.0 2.2 
1 3 2 1 2.0 2.2
1 3 3 2 2.0 2.2
2 1 1 2 1.4 2.5
2 1 2 2 1.4 2.5
2 1 3 2 1.4 2.5
2 2 1 0 1.6 3.0
2 2 2 1 1.6 3.0
2 2 3 1 1.6 3.0
2 3 1 0 2.35 2.9
2 3 2 0 2.35 2.9
2 3 3 2 2.35 2.9
3 1 1 0 2.0 2.9
3 1 2 1 2.0 2.9
3 1 3 2 2.0 2.9
3 2 1 1 0.7 2.5
3 2 2 1 0.7 2.5
3 2 3 2 0.7 2.5
3 3 1 1 0.2 2.1
3 3 2 1 0.2 2.1
3 3 3 2 0.2 2.1
```

How to create such output file with awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you appear to be asking for is:

```
awk '{                 
  y = $2; 
  for(z=1;z<=3;z++){
     value = z < $3 ? 0 : z > $4 ? 2 : 1; 
    $2 = y OFS z OFS value; 
    print
  }
}' file
```

however I can't make it produce the output shown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works as expected ...! The discrepeny is due to the sample out file is not properly written. I will edit the sample file now.